# JQuery AJAX get not working correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial view with this jquery script:

```
$("#btnGetEmpInfo").click(function () {
          var selectedItem = $('#EmployeeId').val();
          var focusItem = $('#EmployeeId')
      alert("Starting");
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("getEmpInfo", "NewEmployee")%>?sData=" + selectedItem,
            data: "{}",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                alert("Yeah!");
                } else {
                   alert("No data returned!");
                }
              }                   
            });
            alert("Back!");
      });
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult getEmpInfo(string sData)
    {
        return new JsonResult { Data = "test" };
    }
```

I can breakpoint in the controller and it is hitting, but the only "Alerts" I get are the "Starting" and "Back".  Why would the data not be returned or at least hit saying no data returned?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably might want to improve this ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '<%= Url.Action("getEmpInfo", "NewEmployee")%>',
    data: { sData: selectedItem },
    success: function(data) {
        // Warning: your controller action doesn't return an array
        // so don't expect a .length property here. See below
        alert(data.Data);
    }                   
});
```

and have your controller action accept GET requests:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult getEmpInfo(string sData)
{
    return Json(new { Data = "test" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

OK, now that we have fixed the error let me elaborate. In your code you were using an `application/json` content type to format your request string. Unfortunately in ASP.NET MVC 2 there is nothing out of the box that is capable of making sense of JSON requests (unless you wrote a [custom json value provider factory](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)). Then using string concatenation to append the `sData` parameter to the URL without ever URL encoding it meaning that your code would break at the very moment the user enters some special character such as `&` in the `EmployeeId` textbox.

Comment: Although it's prettier, it still does not hit the alerts as stated above.

Comment: @George, how about [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com)? Did you try it? Did you see what's sent as request and the response from the server? Did you remove the `?sData=" + selectedItem` from the url part of your request? Did you remove the `application/json` content type from your request? Did you add the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your server controller action? Did you remove the `data.length` in the success callback?

Comment: My apologies...didn't read all the way through.  Added the part for the controller and now returns "No data"  even though it is passing back test.  Hmmm.....

Comment: @George, did you remove the `data.length` test in your `success` callback? Your server doesn't send an array so don't expect a length property.

Comment: That did it.  Once again thanks for your help.  I truly appreciated it.  Nice to know users out there who can help us MVC newbies!  ;-)

Comment: Darin, so using the above, it returns fine but when I try to view the results in the Jquery, it always shows as [object].  I tried returning a list and getitng the length but show undefined.  How can I view the results?  Bottomw line what I want to do is update the model info and then display that.  Make sense?

Comment: @George, use FireBug and then `console.log(data);`. It will show you the object.

Comment: Okay, using Firebug data shows as:
{"Data":["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"]}
How do I read it on the return?

BTW:  I changed return to be a List.

Comment: `data.Data[0]` will give you `Item 1`, ... Or simply use $.each to loop through it.

Comment: So if I did a return of the model data, would I be able to see it there?  Meaning:
NewEmployeeModel myModel = new NewEmployeeModel();
            myModel.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(sData);
            myModel.Department = "IT";
            myModel.FirstName = "George";
            myModel.LastName = "Test";
  return Json(new { Data = myModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Actually tried it and it returned exactly what I want.  Thanks for your patience's.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'beforeSend', 'error' and 'complete' callbacks to get more info in your javascript debugger. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Are you using a javascript debugger? (firebug, ie9 dev-tools, chrome dev-tools are decent ones 3 that come to mind)